# How does the detector at the double slit work?

Tags: double-slit-experiment

How are the particles in the double slit experiment detected when we detect them going through one slit or the other? My assumption has been that the detector itself must interact with the particle in some way, is this the case? How did the first detectors work? How do modern detectors work?